# Mac Os X remote from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop, mac-osx-server, vnc

I want to rent a Mac X dedicated server online. I have only a PC running windows at work. Can a vnc client on windows connect to the Mac Os X Server ? I have read that the protocol Apple Remote Desktop might compatible with vnc, but I want to be sure.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSX server has a built-in VNC server (as do OSX workstations).  This works fine with viewers like UltraVNC which is what I use to connect to a OSX workstation on my network.

If your provider is going to perform initial configuration of the server for you, be sure to confirm with them that you want VNC turned on and have them set a password.  If you will have access to the machine for initial configuration, you can turn on the VNC server in System Preferences > Sharing and enable Screen Sharing.  Then the Computer Settings button will let you set a password.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Remote Desktop server is compatible with standard VNC clients (however I believe you need to manually enable VNC in the Remote Desktop settings panel & set a VNC password).